CORS error getting resource made available via PreSignedUrl from AWS S3 storage
In my .net8 webapi I use the AWSSDK.S3 nuget to generate a pregisnedUrl for a resource previously put in an S3 bucket to get the resource.
In the c# project I retrieve the url like this (put some comments in it for clarity):
public string CreatePreSignedUrl(string key, string userId)
{
try 
{
    var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
    {
        BucketName = _bucketName,
        Key = $"{userId}/{key}",
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
    };
    var result = _amazonS3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
    return result;
}
catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
{
    // Log AWS S3 specific exceptions
    _logger.LogError($"An error occurred with AWS S3: {e.Message}");
    return string.Empty;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Log other exceptions
    _logger.LogError($"An error occurred: {e.Message}");
    return string.Empty;
}

}
When I try to GET the resource using my frontend app, which is on NextJs, I get CORS error:

Access to fetch at
'https://pictures-storage-dev.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/{rest-of-preSignedUrl}'
from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by
CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

The flow:

The backend returns a pure string to the frontend, which is the preSignedUrl
this url is what the frontend tries to reach.

Ofc. the link is accessible when trying to reach it manually but the CORS is not set correctly.
Where and how to set the CORS policy to make the above use case work?

Show your C# code so community can see exactly what you are doing.

Ok, but there are not much code related, editing original post
